# XMLHttpRequest and S3, CORS error

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, cors

I host my photos on S3 bucket. I added CORS configuration for S3 bucket:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
 <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
 <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
 <ExposeHeader>Accept-Ranges</ExposeHeader>
 <ExposeHeader>Content-Range</ExposeHeader>
 <ExposeHeader>Content-Encoding</ExposeHeader>
 <ExposeHeader>Content-Length</ExposeHeader>
 <ExposeHeader>Access-Control-Allow-Origin</ExposeHeader>
 <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

In my html page, I tried to save image, so I am using the library: https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image

```
domtoimage.toBlob(document.getElementById('my-node'))
.then(function (blob) {
    window.saveAs(blob, 'my-node.png');
});
```

I got the CORS error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://s3/bucket/path/image.png.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Any Suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Clear your browser cache?

Comment: I did clear the cache, but still no luck ... :-(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After long debugging, I found the core issue. All S3 CORS configuration were corrected, nothing to do with the S3. The issue came from the browser caching. This annoying caching prevented S3 response Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in response, and that's why it caused the error.

The solution: (it's a hacky solution but it worked)
I added one line of code in method `getAndEncode` of dom-to-image.js to prevent the browser caching.

```
function getAndEncode(url) {
        ...
        url += "?"+(new Date()).getTime(); // this line of code made magic.

        return new Promise(function (resolve) {
            ....
            request.open('GET', url, true);
...
```

Again, this is a hacky way, I am still opening for any better solution.

Comment: Please post back if you found a better solution. Just ran into this myself. I had even cleared 'all' cache in Chrome, but apparently this aspect is still cached. Thanks Chrome for waisting an hour of my life.

Comment: You're my hero. I've been running in circles changing up CORS configurations and not making any progress. Didn't realize browser caching is screwing things up!