# Uploading formData file from client to S3 using createPresignedPost or getPresignedUrl fails due to CORS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, fetch, multipartform-data

I'm using a React web app and trying to upload a file to AWS S3.
I've tried everything both locally (`localhost:3000`) and when deployed to production (Vercel serverless functions).

I first use a fetch to retrieve a presigned url for the file upload, which works perfectly:

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
    let {fileName, fileType} = req.body;
    const post = await s3.createPresignedPost({
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Fields: {
            key: fileName
        },
        ContentType: fileType,
        Expires: 60
    });
    res.status(200).json(post);
```

Then, in the second fetch:

```
await fetch(url, {method: 'POST', body: formData}
```

I'm getting:

```
fetch has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
```

I have set up the Permissions -> CORS json in the bucket configuration correctly:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*",
            "Content-*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "HEAD",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
]
```

I also verified the bucket name in my code.

I've tried:

- Both `getPresignedUrl` & `createPresignedPost` to generate the url
- Both `PUT` & `POST` requests
- Setting headers (`Content-Type`, `x-amz-acl`) in the fetch request
- Using different CORS jsons, allowing all origins, expose different headers, allowing all methods (including `HEAD`, allowing different headers (like `"Content-*"`)
- Configuring different users with different permissions (specifically what I need, all S3 permissions, etc)
- [Settings bucket policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60591506/1380370)
- Clearing Chrome's cache (using Hard Reload) or by [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43345708/xmlhttprequest-and-s3-cors-error) before every try

I've tried everything and went over dozens of articles ([1](https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-s3-post-signed-urls/), [2](https://softwareontheroad.com/aws-s3-secure-direct-upload/?fbclid=IwAR1jBq7ffT9hxIqZJLe9iUXZKVTZNI5tlB445o9L1QXMGZgCFA1zqZNyh7g)) and browsing through questions here - but it's still not working. Not locally and not in production.

Comment: I can't spot a specific issue. However I can provide a working solution that I just tried as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After endless hours of digging into this, I found the issue.
The reason for the CORS error was that I didn't include the `region` in the initial `AWS.config.update` configuration setup.

Once I added the `region` key, the CORS error was solved:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: 'XXXXX',
    secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXX',
    region: 'us-west-2', // Must be the same as your bucket
});

const s3Client = new AWS.S3();
```

It's really confusing and misleading that the error returned for not configuring the bucket region is CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file name match exactly with `Key`

```
const bucketParms = {
  Bucket: "sample-temp-bucket",
  Key: "HeadShot.jpg",
  Expires: 3600,
};

s3.getSignedUrl("putObject", bucketParms, (error, url) => {
  if (error) console.log("error", error);
  if (url) console.log("url", url);
});
```

Right here we can test the url generated from [postman or curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65763592/i-get-nosuchkey-error-after-generating-presigned-url/65763951#65763951)

Then we can make a http `PUT` call.

```
this.http
  .put(
    "https://sample-temp-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/HeadShot.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC....",
    formData
  )
  .subscribe((response) => {
    console.log("response received is ", response);
  });
```

and the CORS, wild card for `ExposeHeaders` is not accepting(at least from console), it worked with just empty array `"ExposeHeaders": []`

Comment: Verified all of those things and I'm still getting the same error:
`Access to fetch at 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
FileUpload.jsx:34 POST https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name net::ERR_FAILED`

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above items fix this for you, also check to make sure you have your bucket set correctly.